# Ng-model not working for attribute directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple controller:

```
.controller("TestController",['$scope', function($scope) {
    this.p = {};
    this.p.name = "Foo";
    this.p.surname = "Bar";
}]);
```

And I have a directive calling this controller:

```
app.directive('cronosDataset',[function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller:'TestController',
    controllerAs: "ctrl",
    scope: {
        cronosDataset : "@"
    }
  };
}])
```

If I call the controller using ng-controller the `ng-model` works fine. But if I call it through the directive it doesn't update the view:

```
<!-- This works -->
Works
<br/>
<div class="sideMenu">
  <form ng-controller="TestController as ctrl">
      Name: <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.p.name" />
      Surname: <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.p.surname" />
  </form>
</div>

<!-- This one doesn't work -->
Doesn't work
<br/>
<div class="sideMenu">
  <form cronos-dataset="People">
      Name2: <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.p.name" />
      Surname2: <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.p.surname" />
  </form>
</div>
```

**Edit:** I can put it to work if I don't use isolated scope (`scope : {...}` in directive definition). I'm only using isolated scope to have access to this attribute `scope: { cronosDataset : "@" }` inside my controller. If there's a different way to do it without use isolated scope then problem solved!

What I'm trying to archive is to reuse the logic I have done to get data from database Example:

```
<form cronos-dataset="People"><input type="text" ng-model="p.name" /></form>
<form cronos-dataset="Car"><input type="text" ng-model="p.model" /></form>
<form cronos-dataset="Address"><input type="text" ng-model="p.street" /></form>
```

In my controller I go to `database` (ajax using `cronos-dataset` as query parameter) and put the result back in `p` variable. So i need two things:

```
1 - Have access to attribute inside the controller
2 - Update the ng-model with a scope variable
```

Does it make sense?

Here is a [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/XJICoS0X4dzE4WcwsEgB?p=preview)

Comment: The directive defines an isolated scope, that is why the `ctrl` is not available.

Comment: Is that a way to make the directive scope available for children nodes?

Comment: Do you really need isolated scope?

Comment: In my controller. I'm reading a value from the database and setting into `p` variable. I want reuse this component by only changing `cronus-dataset` attribute to point to another dataset. That's why I need it

Comment: your plunker doesn't make any sense.  your first example doesn't use your directive at all, and your second example tries to use the directive like it's a controller (it's not).  the second example has nothing to bind to.  Can you try to explain a bit more about what you are really trying to accomplish?

Comment: it appears to me that you are trying to use the controller in the directive on the elements that are outside the directive.  Keep in mind, that even though the input boxes in your HTML are nested inside your directive element, they do not actually belong to the directive, and are not affected by it's scope.  They still belong to the parent element.  If you want the elements that are nested inside to be affected, you have to use transclusion.

Comment: I want to go to database with table `People`, get the data and put on scope variable `p`. If I use `cronos-dataset="Car"` I want to have access to 'Car' string inside my controller to get data from `Car`  table instead of `People`. Does it make sense? I want to reuse the logic I have done to all my entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3BKYED5VWQt60IEe4r18?p=preview) to add Transclusion.  The Directive Transcludes the element, replacing it entirely.  It then takes the cloned (original contents) and inserts them into the Transclusion, making the original elements become compiled as part of the directive.

```
app.directive('cronosDataset',[function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller:'TestController',
    controllerAs: "ctrl",
    scope: {
        cronosDataset : "@"
    },
    transclude: 'element',
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
      transclude(scope, function(clone) {
        elem.after(clone);
      });
    }
  };
}])
```

Comment: It's magic! It works like a charm now. I would give you 10 up votes if I could.