# Isolating scope in directive, when wrapping html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
{{var1}}
<div customdirective var2="var1">
Isolated: {{var2}}
</div>

[...].directive("customdirective", function() {

return {
scope: {
      var2 : "="
   }
}

});
```

Does not work....
If, instead, I assign a template with inside {{var2}} it work.

Why?

Comment: I answered a very similar question a few days ago... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857942/ng-model-not-working-for-attribute-directive/28859667#28859667

Comment: Thanks for your answer.... I achieved the same using "compile" inside of the directive. I'm still a bit confused why angular behaves this way.

Comment: basically, it has to do with the rendering order of the DOM elements.  Transclusion is never really explained well.  To explain it in one sentence, transclusion consists of plucking out the content of a custom directive, processing it against the right scope and then placing it at a marked position in the template of that directive.  Basically, Angular has to re-order the rendering in order to process the right variables at the right times.

Answer (score 0):

In above example custom directive is attribute where var2 is isolated from parent scope var1. 
var2 will not be available Isolated: {{var2}} what you used.
you need template or template URL to use var2.

Here problem is the scope of directive is isolated scope.

Answer (score 0):

The variable named "var2" refers to a value of a controller scope.
You can't use the isolated scope of directive at the location where you use the directive.

I would recommend for you to use a template if you have to use the isolated scope value.

The section named "Creating a Directive that Wraps Other Elements" on [angularjs doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) would help you.

Comment: Thank for your time and answer. I read the documentation where explains how to transclude in order to access the parent scope. What i want to achieve here is to isolate the content of the element with the directive. Claies linked the working code.... still a bit confusing that the scope kicks in with a template but not inline...