# How to access isolated $scope in customer AngularJS directive without remote template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

How do I get the isolated scope working within a customer directive that doesn't have a remote template?

The following is not working for me.

AnularJS

```
app.directive('emanForm', ['$http', 'db', function ($http, db) {
    return {

        scope: { },

        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

            $scope.message = 'test';

        }

    };
}]);
```

HTML

```
<form name="form_1" eman-form="form1">
    {{ message }}
</form>
```

The $scope seems to be only available when I include a remote template. `templateUrl: 'view.html'` etc...

Comment: the expression inside that form is not part of the directive, it is part of the element tree that renders that form.  If you want the element to be a part of the directive, you need to use transclusion.

Comment: I answered a question similar a few weeks ago, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857942/ng-model-not-working-for-attribute-directive/28859667#28859667.  The code isn't exactly the same, but the concept should be identical.

Comment: Yup, ``transclude:'element'`` is the right way to go.

Comment: also, your link function should be using `scope`, not `$scope`.

Comment: scope or $scope, it doesn't matter. There's no injection here. He could name it foobar if he wanted. His code would run the same. Naming it scope is indeed better though, not to confuse it with the injected $scope in the controller.

Comment: Adding `transclude:'element'` doesn't work. It causes all my dom elements to disappear!

Comment: @Emmanuel, if you do `transclude: 'element'`, then you should also do `element.after` to re-insert it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question here is not about remote vs. local template, but rather an expression in the child DOM vs. in the template.

The child elements of the element hosting a directive are not in the scope created by that directive - they and the directive are siblings for scope purposes.

So, `{{message}}` will be evaluated at the parent's scope.

To "bring these elements into the scope" requires the use of `$compile`:

```
link: function(scope, element){
  $compile(element.contents())(scope);  
}
```

**EDIT:**

The approach above causes the contents to be compiled twice - once in the normal course of compilation, and second time - with `$compile`. This is of course sub-optimal.

To avoid that, a manual approach would have been to `$compile` and remove the contents of the element in the directive's `compile` function, and then link the compiled contents and add/append them to the element in the `link` function.

Instead of this, Angular provides transclusion. When `transclude: true` (or `transclude: 'element'`), the contents are compiled once and a clone of the transcluded content, bound to a scope specified by the transclude function, is available to be placed anywhere.

```
transclude: 'element',
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transcludeFn){
  // bind to the directive's scope
  transcludeFn(scope, function(clone){
    // element here is the comment element left after transclusion
    element.after(clone); 
  });
```

Comment: this answer is a good alternative to using transclude for simple evaluations.

Comment: When angular executes the link function, it has already compiled the contents of the element. This could work, but I think the best way to go is to use transclusion.

Comment: @jlowcs, yes - agreed. I'll fix the answer